# Как посчитать сумму всего столбца таблицы?

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется таблица:

```
<table border="1" id='testTable'>
    <caption>Тестовая таблица</caption>
    <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td>Параметр</td>
             <th>x</th>
             <th>y</th>
             <th>z</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>xyz(1)</td>
             <td>5</td>
             <td>4</td>
             <td>12</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>xyz(2)</td>
             <td>16</td>
             <td>25</td>
             <td>14.1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>xyz(3)</td>
             <td>12.1</td>
             <td>14.2</td>
             <td>7.4</td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Как, например, получить сумму всего 2 столбца (y)?
4 + 25 + 14.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let table = document.querySelector("#testTable");

console.log( col_sum(table, 1) ); // 0 (нет чисел в столбике)

console.log( col_sum(table, 2) );
console.log( col_sum(table, 3) );
console.log( col_sum(table, 4) );

console.log( col_sum(table, 9) ); // 0 (нет такого столба)

/***/
function col_sum(table, col) {
  let sum = 0, tr = table.querySelectorAll("tr"); // Все tr внутри table.
  
  for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    let td = tr[i].querySelectorAll("td"); // Все td внутри строки; th не учитываем.

    if (!td.length || !td[col - 1]) continue;
    // В tr нет td, или есть, но такого столбика не существует.
    
    sum += Number( td[col - 1].textContent ) || 0;
    // Если в textContent не число, Number вернет NaN, возьмется 0 вместо него.
  }
  
  return sum;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id='testTable'>
  <caption>Тестовая таблица</caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Параметр</td>
      <th>x</th>
      <th>y</th>
      <th>z</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>xyz(1)</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>xyz(2)</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>14.1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>xyz(3)</td>
      <td>12.1</td>
      <td>14.2</td>
      <td>7.4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```